# Link to network profile from stackexchange.com itself

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, stackexchange.com, network-profile

On any SE domain, I can click my profile link in the top bar and I'm presented with a network profile link (to https://stackexchange.com/users/[0-9]+/ ):

[image: Network profile link]

But when I'm on https://stackexchange.com/ itself, I can't find any way to reach my network profile. There is no link in the top bar, nor in the footer, nowhere:
[image: SE.com top bar]
I'm forced to click a link to another domain, then reach my profile, then the network profile.

**Proposal**: add a network profile link in the stackexchange.com top bar. For instance next to "Stack Exhange" in the "Current community" drop down, so that you don't have to design a special "Inbox" or "Achievements" dropdown. There is already a [custom "chat" link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=stackexchange.com) anyway:

[image: Current communities]

Use case: I'm looking for a post but I don't remember where it was. I first use the SE-wide search from the stackexchange.com main page, but I don't nail it. I want to reach my network profile to search within my favorites.

Comment: In my topbar on SE.com I see my avatar just left of the inbox. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjNBr.png  That seems to be missing from your screnshots. Clicking it brings me on my se networkwide page

Comment: @rene oh you're right, the link is actually there but [the avatar is blank](https://stackexchange.com/users/1405710/nemo) for whatever reason, so the link is invisible.

Comment: I can see yours ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uqMT.png

Comment: Should this maybe be marked "no longer reproducible"? (If you're still having this issue, I figure it should be submitted as a new bug report, rather than this request for a feature that already exists.)

Comment: @V2Blast I'm fine with that, I don't know how to do it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you note, it's caused by the fact that your avatar isn't shown to you on stackexchange.com (but it is for rene and me). That's more a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) / [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) issue.

As a workaround, you can always navigate to this link:
https://stackexchange.com/users/current to get to your network profile, or visit it from the link on one of your site profiles (as you already mentioned as a workaround).

Comment: No caching, many ISP and work places block imgur.com domain due to the nature of many images hosted there. It's also blocked country-wide in many places, e.g. China and Iran.

Answer (score 4):

You can also reach your own network profile via the drawer icon: (Recent inbox messages)

> [image: open drawer icon]

The "all items" links to the [inbox tab of the network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox), from which you can go to all other tabs.